# Graph In Android Using AChartEngine

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, achartengine, graphical-layout-editor

Problem Is that i am not able to fit the graph according to screen. some of the portion of graph is cutting by right side.I tried lot to set the margin from Right but nothing works for me.As You can see in attached image the last bar is cutting by half. Please anyone help me.

[image]

```
*layout.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:shrinkColumns="6"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#4CC1D2"
            android:padding="4dip" >
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_span="1"
                android:onClick="gotoback"
                android:background="#4CC1D2"
                android:src="@drawable/backb" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/currentMonth"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_span="5"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="How You want to Track"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-18dp"
                android:textSize="21sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:shrinkColumns="9"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#E6E6E6"
            android:padding="5dip" >
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/lstweek" />
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="getmonth"
                android:src="@drawable/lstm" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:background="#4CC1D2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="getmonth1"
                android:src="@drawable/all" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/logs7"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#4CC1D2"
            android:onClick="alllogs"
            android:text="View Logs"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>*


Activity Java file.


     public class CalorieConsumedTrackerActivity extends Activity {

    private GraphicalView mChart;
    JSONArray dailydata = null;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private static String url_display_user ;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_RESPONSE = "getdata";
    JSONArray graphdatas = null;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getdata;
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    String userid=null;
    String[] mMonth = new String[7] ;
    String[] datefromdb = new String[7] ;

    int[] x = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int[] target = new int[7];
    int[] consumed = new int[7];

    int[]showtarget=new int[7];
    int[]showconsumed=new int[7];



    XYSeries incomeSeries = new XYSeries("Target");
    // Creating an  XYSeries for Expense
    XYSeries expenseSeries = new XYSeries("Consumed");
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calories_consumed ); 

        getdata=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        DatabaseHandler db=new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        user=db.getUserDetails();
        userid=user.get("userid");

        Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        myCalendar.set(myCalendar.getTime().getYear()+1900,myCalendar.getTime().getMonth() , myCalendar.getTime().getDate());
        for (int i = 6; i >=0; i--) {
            myCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String date = sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()); 
            System.out.println(date);
            mMonth[i]=date;
        }

        new GetGraphData().execute();
    }

    private void openChart(){

    }   

    class GetGraphData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(CalorieConsumedTrackerActivity.this, "wait", "Fetching...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            url_display_user = "http://www.bharatwellness.com/getGraphData.php";

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> parametres = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            parametres.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", userid));

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_display_user,
                    "GET", parametres);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All data : ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                JSONObject c=null;

                if (success == 1) {
                    int i;
                    int cal=0;
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    graphdatas = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESPONSE);

                    // looping through All RESPONSE
                    for (i = 0; i < graphdatas.length(); i++) {

                        c = graphdatas.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable

                        String createddate = c.getString("createddate");
                        datefromdb[i]=createddate;
                        String caloriegoal = c.getString("caloriegoal");
                        String calorieconsumed = c.getString("calorieconsumed");
                        double cgoal=Double.parseDouble(caloriegoal);
                        cal=(int) Math.round(cgoal);
                        target[i]=cal;
                        double csumed=Double.parseDouble(calorieconsumed);
                        int calc=(int) Math.round(csumed);
                        consumed[i]=calc;

                    }


                    for(int x=0;x<mMonth.length;x++){

                        for(int y=0;y<datefromdb.length;y++){

                            if(mMonth[x].equals(datefromdb[y])){

                                showconsumed[x]=consumed[y];
                                showtarget[x]=target[y];


                            }
                            if(showtarget[x]==0){

                                showtarget[x]=cal;
                            }


                        }

                    }


                    // Creating an  XYSeries for Income

                    // Adding data to Income and Expense Series
                    for(int j=0;j<x.length;j++){
                        incomeSeries.add(x[j], showtarget[j]);
                        expenseSeries.add(x[j],showconsumed[j]);
                    }

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            // Creating a dataset to hold each series
                            XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
                            // Adding Income Series to the dataset
                            dataset.addSeries(incomeSeries);
                            // Adding Expense Series to dataset
                            dataset.addSeries(expenseSeries);       


                            // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize incomeSeries
                            XYSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
                            incomeRenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#04B431"));
                            incomeRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
                            incomeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
                            incomeRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
                            incomeRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(20);

                            incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);


                            // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize expenseSeries
                            XYSeriesRenderer expenseRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
                            expenseRenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF8000"));
                            expenseRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
                            expenseRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
                            expenseRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
                            expenseRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(20);

                            expenseRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);


                            for(int z=0;z<mMonth.length;z++){
                                String createddate=mMonth[z];
                                String month=createddate.substring(5, 7);
                                System.out.println(month);
                                int m=Integer.parseInt(month);
                                System.out.println(m);
                                switch (m) {
                                case 1:
                                    month="Jan";
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    month="Feb";
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    month="Mar";
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    month="Apr";
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                    month="May";
                                    break;
                                case 6:
                                    month="June";
                                    break;
                                case 7:
                                    month="July";
                                    break;
                                case 8:
                                    month="Aug";
                                    break;
                                case 9:
                                    month="Sep";
                                    break;
                                case 10:
                                    month="Oct";
                                    break;
                                case 11:
                                    month="Nov";
                                    break;

                                case 12:
                                    month="Dec";
                                    break;
                                }

                                String day=createddate.substring(8, 10);

                                String finaldate= day+" "+month;



                                mMonth[z]=finaldate ;




                            }


                            // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
                            XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
                            multiRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(30);
                            multiRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                            multiRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.WHITE);
                            multiRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
                            multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
                            multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Calories Consumed Progress Chart");

                            multiRenderer.setGridColor(Color.WHITE);
                            multiRenderer.setXTitle("");
                            multiRenderer.setYTitle("Calories");
                            multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
                            multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(4);
                            multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
                            multiRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(20);
                            multiRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);

                            multiRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
                            multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(3000);
                            multiRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
                            multiRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
                            double panLimits[]={20,20,20,20};
                            multiRenderer.setPanLimits(panLimits);

                            multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
                            for(int i=0;i<mMonth.length;i++){
                                multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i+1, mMonth[i]);  
                                multiRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(20);
                                int mar[]={20,20,20,20};
                                multiRenderer.setMargins(mar);
                                multiRenderer.setGridColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                            }       

                            // Adding incomeRenderer and expenseRenderer to multipleRenderer
                            // Note: The order of adding dataseries to dataset and renderers to multipleRenderer
                            // should be same
                            multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(incomeRenderer);
                            multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(expenseRenderer);
                            multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(false);

                            // Getting a reference to LinearLayout of the MainActivity Layout
                            LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_container);
                            chartContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);




                            LinearLayout con = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);
                            con.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);





                            // Specifying chart types to be drawn in the graph
                            // Number of data series and number of types should be same
                            // Order of data series and chart type will be same
                            String[] types = new String[] { LineChart.TYPE, BarChart.TYPE };

                            // Creating a combined chart with the chart types specified in types array
                            mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getCombinedXYChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer, types);


                            mChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                            multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
                            multiRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);
                            multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(false);
                            mChart.setMinimumWidth(100);

                            // Adding the Combined Chart to the LinearLayout
                            chartContainer.addView(mChart,layoutParams);  



                        }});


                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products



            progressDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }


}


![enter image description here][2]
```

Comment: how about using ScrollView as the chart container?

Comment: @yummy I don't want to put the horizontal scrollView  for the graph. Is it anything which can fit  according to screen

Comment: What about rotating the date labels? You'd get some more horizontal space.

Comment: have you checked this link ? a better and efficient alternative for achartengine lib(graph library) which is  **MPAndroidChart** https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: Something like `renderer.setXLabelsAngle(45.0f);`. This will rotate them 45°.

Comment: @ScionofIkshvaku  I have already implemented it  by Using AchartEngine library.Only issue with the Adjustment.

Comment: The most horizontal space (obviously) is obtained with a labels angle of 90°.

Comment: @DerGolem     Still The Last Bar Is cutting By Half see at link                                                           http://postimg.org/image/dvqx1699n/

Comment: Consider reducing the font size for the labels. Also try increasing the angle 60° will give you more horizontal space. Maximum space at 90° (vertical labels)